# Show Capslock on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8

just got a new Samsung laptop running Windows 8. The laptop keyboard has no indication if capslock enabled or not. Is there some way I can get it to display in the system tray, or to flash on the screen when it changes?

Comment: Unbelievable Windows 8 doesn't have a built in indicator for the taskbar!!!

Answer (score 5):

You can make it beep by going to *Control panel > Ease of Access > Make the Keyboard Easeier to Use*.  Check the box next to *Turn on Toggle Keys*.

I found this answer for Windows 7, it may also work for Windows 8.

1. Click *Start*
2. Type *Keyboard* in the search field
3. Double click on *Keyboard options*
4. Under Key Settings tab, go to the *Key Settings List*
5. Locate and double click on *CAPS LOCK*
6. On the menu you should see where it says *Display CAPS LOCK status on screen*
7. Click the checkbox, and click *Finish*

Comment: That helps, but something on screen would be nice.

Comment: I can't find comparable settings that work for Windows 8.

Comment: no similar function in Windows 10 either

Answer (score 3):

I just bought my new laptop which didn't had a CapsLock light so I wrote a quick AutoHotkey script which will change tray icon based on the current capslock status. You can find it here.

http://aviaryan.in/blog/capslock-notifier-released.html

The source is on [GitHub](https://github.com/aviaryan/autohotkey-scripts/tree/master/Tools/capslockstatus)

Comment: +1 Works fine, I jus changed the icons, now looks cool

Comment: The source code is 8KB but the exe is 304KB. Why the big difference?

Comment: @AlikElzin-kilaka The code is in AutoHotkey, a scripting language. The interpreter is packed with the source to make the executable.

Answer (score 0):

This tiny & free software can be used in Windows platform to know status of Num Lock and Caps Lock

https://sourceforge.net/projects/keyboard-status/?source=directory

Answer (score -1):

Change the registry location: 
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Widcomm\BTConfig\General\KeyIndication 
from 0 to 1, and then restart.

This produces a text notification in the bottom right corner of the screen displaying "CAPS LOCK: ON" or "CAPS LOCK: OFF" for 3 seconds.

It worked on my laptop (Thinkpad T430 Win8.1 x64).

Comment: that's specific to your machine.